# UpgradeAPI for Google Apps MarketPlace from OAuth 1.0 to OAuth 2.0

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I am having an application listed on Google apps marketplace for Calendar Integration. As it was OAuth 1.0 but now I am migrating my application to OAuth 2.0. We have some steps specified on `https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v1migratev2` over here. But When I am following these steps then I am getting 401 (Unauthorized). Kindly check the below code what I doing for migrating a domain.

```
        String url = String.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/upgradableApp/{0}/{1}/{2}", oldAppId, chromeListing, domain);            
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "PUT";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth");
        Hashtable postObj = new Hashtable();
        postObj["Consumer Key"] = oldClientId;
        postObj["Consumer Key Secret"] = oldSecret;
        String s1 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(postObj);
        var bs = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s1);
        using (Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            reqStream.Write(bs, 0, bs.Length);
        }
        String result = "";
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
            }
        }
```

Does any one having the information regarding, how we need to migrate our old users to the new application. I am already follow all the steps provided in the above link. Thanks in advance.